# source code is correct but not the output in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

When I see the source code it is fine but when I check the inspect element f12 in chrome,it is completelty messed up and i don't get desired output. It is working fine on other browsers like firefox, IE etc and output is also correct.
[image: screenshot of my error]

please someone help me to know about the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: actually this is working for others except me. so just posted the screenshot so that you can get some idea seeing the inspect element code

Comment: Is this the effect of some extension is my doubt

Comment: did you applied those prettyprint class ?????

Comment: no I didnt apply and it is not present the source code.

Comment: it is applied by plugin of your browser ie pretty print

Comment: yeah thanks I found the bug around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys,

As I expected, the behavior was due to some extension which I was using. I deleted few of them and the problem disappeared sorry for my question.

Thanks for reply.

Learning: **Even extensions can create problems sometimes.**